# difference between type arg[] and type *arg

Tags: c++, args

When it comes to function parameters type arg[] is equivalent to type *arg and in fact, the later is more accurate because you can't pass arrays as function arguments, they are always implicitly converted to pointer to type. So with that in mind, I'm assuming this doesn't work, and it doesn't! But I don't know how to fix it. I think I might have it backwards

```
 Polygon::Polygon(int num_points, double x_array[], double y_array[])
 {
    this->num_points = num_points;
    for (int k = 0; k < num_points; k++)
    {
      x_array[k] = points[k].GetX();
      y_array[k] = points[k].GetY();
    }
  }
```

I am taking values from the uninitialized member *array points* and assigning them to the arrays passed in by the arguments. Is there another way to write it? I can give the entire code if you want

Comment: "this doesn't work". Please explain what the intended results are, what the actual results are, and how you observe them. Also please don't use arrays. Use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: Or `std::array` for that matter.

Comment: @n.m.                                                                     this is the output that I receive:                           (-12,8)
(3,4)
(0, 0)
(0, 0)
(0, 0)
(0, 0)
(0, 0)
(0, 0)

Comment: @suitedupvet83 Note that `a[b]` is equivalent to `*(a + b)` when `a` is a pointer or array type, so yes, indexing a pointer does work when that pointer is to the first element of an array and you stay within the bounds of the array.

Comment: You posted a whole bunch of code but you still haven't adequately explain what the problem is.

Comment: @greatwolf I need to create some methods with arrays as parameters. I'm having trouble getting the methods (both AddPoint methods, the overloaded constructor, and the SetPoints method all fail to work. When I use the overloaded constructor / the addpoint methods, they return a strange value for all the values, this is the output: (-12,8) (3,4) (0, 0) (0, 0) (0, 0) (0, 0) (0, 0) (0, 0)  and when i use SetPoints it does not return anything at all (ex. if I use SetPoints for SecondPoly, there would only be 3 sets of "(0,0)"

Comment: So, does it "work" if you change the signature to `Polygon::Polygon(int num_points, double* x_array, double* y_array)`? If not, then you are asking the wrong question. If yes, your compiler is broken.

Comment: **Please explain what the intended results are** and why you expect them. What value num_points has? What value points has? Why are you copying points and num_points in opposite directions?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to change this

```
x_array[k] = points[k].GetX();
y_array[k] = points[k].GetY();
```

to something like this

```
points[k] = Point(x_array[k], y_array[k]);
```